# Mocking a method twice in python with different values

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have to mock a method shown below:

#### Actual python method

```
import json
def some_method(self):
    output_one = json.loads(varone)
    output_two = json.loads(vartwo)
```

#### Test Method

```
import json
self.stubs = stubout.StubOutForTesting()
self.stubs.Set(json, "loads", lambda *a: output_one)
self.stubs.Set(json, "loads", lambda *a: output_two)
```

the result is see is only the **output_two** as **output_one** is getting overwritten.
How should i mock a method twice and expect different output each time.

Comment: Are you calling `self.stubs` in between the `Set` with `output_one` and the `Set` with `output_two`? What are you expecting to happen here? Why don't you show us the rest of your code...

Comment: Yes. Am calling Set for output_one and output_two. Now you should have a better picture.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I'm asking you if you do anything in between `self.stubs.Set(json, "loads", lambda *a: output_one)` and `self.stubs.Set(json, "loads", lambda *a: output_two)` or if that's exactly how your code is written.

Comment: In my test case, no i dont. I just mock them. But in my actual code i do use them. How does that help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect).

Example from docs:

```
>>> mock = Mock()
>>> mock.side_effect = [3, 2, 1]
>>> mock(), mock(), mock()
(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code into two test functions.

```
def test_output_one():
    self.stubs = stubout.StubOutForTesting()
    self.stubs.Set(json, "loads", lambda *a: output_one)
    ... code for the first test here ...

def test_output_two():
    self.stubs = stubout.StubOutForTesting()
    self.stubs.Set(json, "loads", lambda *a: output_two)
    ... code for the second test here ...
```

Comment: I dont want to change my python-code. Test case must handle the scenarios.